# How to interpret confidence interval with accuracy phrase

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, references, accuracy

Upon reading a peer reviewed article, I found this:

> A Chi-square test shows that the demographic characteristics of the sample represent Toyota GB’s hybrid customers (data obtained from the New Car Buyers Survey Britain 2007, provided by Toyota GB), with **2.7%** accuracy and 99% confidence.

I totally understand the concept of confidence interval , but I have not seen the accuracy part side by side with the confidence interval, can you explain what it means here specifically, or please point to me where I need to be reading?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my opinion on this. If you think a little about the question, the *intuitive* answer is this: while *confidence interval* describes the **range of mean values** for a sample, *accuracy* of a statistics describes **margin of error** in measuring values. This relation is not to be confused with related, but different, one of accuracy and precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision. Actually, I believe that these relations represent **exactly the same things**, with the only essential difference being **reversed terminology** - what your question and much statistical materials refer to as *confidence interval* and *accuracy*, the above-mentioned Wikipedia article (and potentially other materials out there) refers to as *accuracy* and *precision* (see Figure below).

[image]

A detailed and IMHO very good **explanation** of a relation of and difference between *confidence interval* and *accuracy* can be found in the Chapter 20 of the second edition of Julian Simon's book **"Resampling: The new statistics"**: http://www.resample.com/content/text/24-Chap-20.pdf. All chapters are available online here: http://www.resample.com/intro-text-online.

More confusing (to me), but nevertheless good and more statistically-focused **explanation** is this: http://www.bioconsulting.com/calculation_of_the_confidence_interval.htm.

Finally, another relevant **discussion** can be found here on *Cross Validated* site: [Narrow confidence interval -- higher accuracy?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16164/31372).

It should be noted that often some papers, including statistical ones, use the term *"accuracy"* to denote a **different meaning** in a *specific context*, for example, to describe the ratio of true results of a medical diagnostic test to all results: http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug10/hl/hl07.pdf.

Comment: thank you reply . The graph is very nice in showing the difference between precision and accuracy. I Just wanted to know the meaning of the 2.7% here (in the question) as it is still confusing me , does it mean that we are accurate about the value of the mean of the sample relative to population by (100-2.7=97.3%), or it means that we are sure that the sample value might deviate from the population by 2.7%? (they might be the same...)....

Comment: @Immortal: You're welcome. I think that 2.7% in your quote refers to measurement **precision** (as in the figure above), which is synonymous to the term **accuracy** in some other sources (such as the book I referenced). Feel free to upvote my answer, if you like it.